# How to check if user subscribe to another user via Open Graph Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph, subscribe

Is it a way to check if user subscribe to another with Open Graph (Javascript) ?

Example :

```
FB.api('/me/subscribe/' + username, 'post', { });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
/me/subscribedto
```

You can then go through the returned subscribed to list looking for a particular user